# MongoDb data from windows server to linux

Tags: linux, windows, mongodb, laravel

I have installed MongoDb(for laravel project) on windows and created some Collections.
Now I want my collection and the data in the collection to be accessible on Linux server.
Any Guide line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.

Take a dump of mongodb collection using mongoexport command.

```
mongoexport --db test --collection traffic --out traffic.json.
```

And move the dump file to the linux machines and use the mongoimport command to recreate the collections on Linux.

```
mongoexport --db test --collection traffic --out traffic.json
```

The tutorials can be found at
    http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/.

[OR]

The second option is to directly copy the data/db folder from windows and while starting the mongo in linux machine point the --dbpath to this directory.